# elasticsearch generic query that works for any search

Tags: php, jquery, elasticsearch

I am stuck with generic query for my audit project which consists of over a million+ records. Is there any generic query to generate using my php or jquery code? All I could get is till here where I am using `AND`, `OR` operators to do same:

```
    {
    "filter": {
        "AND": {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "age": "28"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "OR": {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "name": "varsh"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way so I can use any operator and any field to search for? my UI looks something like this [image]

Comment: One thing that's confusing in your UI is grouping. One operation is AND, other is OR. How is that supposed to work? `category = 123 AND name = abc OR age = 23`. Is that supposed to be `(category = 123 AND name = abc) OR (age = 23)` or `(category = 123)` and `(name = abc OR age = 23)`?

Comment: yes @Mave am sorry i did not make that clear thanks for updating... Its (category = 123 AND name = abc) OR (age = 23). I needed a format where in 1 query works as both of us examples with minimal change.

Comment: Always, all the time? What happens when you add a third row that's `AND`, and a fourth, and a fifth, with the fifth being an `OR` again? Make sure the logic you wish to convey is rock solid first.

Comment: that was just an example @mave i needed a format where in it can take any number of AND, OR, NOT

Answer (score 0):

We have quite the same approach in our application. Users can build their own query with a similar UI (the only difference is we have sub-group, so you can have nested queries).

We use an AST to store users queries, something like :

```
["a",["o",[{"t":"generic.content","o":"contains","a":"@username"},{"t":"generic.content","o":"contains","a":"#username"]],["a",[{"t":"generic.content","o":"contains","a":"other thing"},{"t":"generic.content","o":"contains","a":"yet another thing"}]],["o",[{"t":"generic.lang","o":"equals_lang","a":"fr"},{"t":"generic.lang","o":"equals_lang","a":"en"}]]]
```

where ["a", []] is a group with AND operator and ["o", []] a group with OR operator.

Then we use this AST to build an Elasticsearch query using bool query (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) dynamically.

In our format negation is handle at the operator level (contains vs !contains), but you could have a group of NOT operator like ["n", []]